# efficient (non series expansion ?? ) computation of log(P / 1 - P)

Tags: logarithms, power-series

As per the question, where P is a probability $[0,1]$.

The reason for seeking optimisation is that my system will have to
perform $O(10^9)$ such computations per second.

I suspect that a rearrangement of the form:

$\log(P) - \log(1 - P)$

may lead to a simplified series expansion (certain power terms are zeroed) ,
but it will be a series expansion nonetheless.

The only other aid I may have (TBC) , is that P may be of the form:

$P = f(x) = \dfrac{C}{b^x}$

which means

$\log(P / 1 - P) = \log_b(P / 1 - P) \\
= \log_b(P) - \log_b(1 - P) = \log_b(C / b^x) - \log_b(1 -P) \\
= \log_b(C) - \log_b(b^x) - \log_b(1 - P) \\
= \log_b(C) - x - \log_b(1 - P)$

but still potentially a series expansion.

If anyone knows of a decent approximation (perhaps two series add/mult terms
max) for this specific case, I would be very grateful.

TIA.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: I believe [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) will probably give you much better answers.

Comment: Do you know anything about typical values of p? Obviously in the range (0,1) but will they be bunched in the middle or at the end for example? How much precision do you need for the answers? It's not clear to me how it helps to know that $p=c/b^x$ unless you can tell us something about c, b or x.